# Trying to create a multi-functional button using react js {on first click - saves data, turns "view", and on second click - navigate to saved page}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mern

I am trying to create a multi-functional button in React Js (MERN STACK), which is Initially a "Save" button. On click, it should ideally post the row data to MongoDB, once the data is being stored and 200 response status is achieved, it should convert into "VIEW" Button, which will have a link to navigate to View the Saved data Page. I have tried numerous ways, but not able to achieve the required target. What should I do? Your help is really appreciable. Thank You SO much in advance.....!

[Image Link below]

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function SaveButton( {cTag} ) {
    
    //  cTag prop holds the values of row data in object format as shown in the given figure.

    console.log(cTag);
    const [saveBtn, setViewBtn] = useState("Save");

    const {name, symbol, mCap, cVal} = cTag;

    const SaveCompany = () => {
            const companyData = {
                name:name,
                symbol:symbol,
                mCap: mCap,
                cVal: cVal
            }

      
            axios.post('http://localhost:8082/api/books', companyData).then((response) => {
                    
                    console.log(response.status);
                    setViewBtn("View");
                    window.alert("Data Submitted Successfully...!")
    
                }).catch(() => {
                    alert("Data Didnt Save");
                })
            
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button className = "btn btn-sm btn-primary" onClick = {SaveCompany}> {saveBtn} </button>
        </>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is your button turned to "View" once you click on save?

Answer (score 0):

dont call saveCompany from button, you would need another 2 functions, the view and the condition:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  switch(saveBtn) {
    case "Save" : saveCompany(); break;
    case "View" : viewCompany(); break;
  }
}
...
<button className = "btn btn-sm btn-primary" onClick = {handleClick}> {saveBtn} </button>
```